# Pre Calculus Math Equation With Logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

Please Help me with this I think i figured out question 1... but I get no solution... 
please help me start number 2 or if you can show full solution that be sick thanks.

> 1. $\log_{3x}(81)=2$
> 2. $\log_3(\log_x(\log_4 16))=-1$

my attempt for number 1 ! :)

$$\frac{1}{81}\log_{3x}(81)=\frac{2}{81}$$
$$\log_{3x}=2/81$$
$$10^{\large{\log_{3x}}}=10(2/81)$$
$$3x=10 (2/81)$$
$$x=10 (2/81) /3 $$

Comment: number 1 I get no solution please show your solution and help me with number 2 ;

Comment: Is this from an online quiz/test? Because, it surely looks like it.

Comment: The mistake you are making on the first one is that you cannot factor out 81. The statement is not $\log(3x)\cdot 81$, it is $\log_{3x}(81)$, the base 3x logarithm of 81 (and not 81 times the logarithm of 3x).

Comment: I've edited your answer to try to convert to LaTeX, our math formatting software.  Please make sure I'm representing your answer correctly--some things didn't seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I make multiple use of the rule: $\log_a x=b\implies a^b=x$

The first problem is already addressed in one of the other answers, but when you see $\log_{3x}(81)=2$, you should think $(3x)^2=9x^2=81\implies x=3$

As for the second problem, since $4^2=16$, we know that $\log_4 16=2$ and we can make the following simplification:

$$\log_3(\log_x(\log_4 16))=-1\\
\log_3(\log_x(2))=-1$$

Now, if we think of $\log_x(2)$ as a variable, call it $y$, we can rewrite the above equality like so:
$$\log_3 y=-1\\
y=3^{-1}=\frac{1}{3}$$
Now that we have a value for $y$, lets put it back in context:
$$y=\log_x(2)=\frac{1}{3}\\
x^{\frac{1}{3}}=2\\
x=8
$$

Comment: +1 for clear these thing from basic approach.I mention some of the other basic log properties in this link....http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/391655/write-the-expressoin-in-terms-of-log-x-and-log-y-log-fracx310y/391680#391680

Answer (score 0):

$$\log_{3x}(81)=2$$
$$(3x)^{\log_{3x}(81)}=(3x)^{2}$$
$$81=9x^2$$
$$9=x^2$$
$$3=x$$